# Navigating through accordion menu items in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could someone help me to implement prev/next buttons for navigating through accordion menu items? The accordion itself works ok when accordion header is clicked but I should also implement a prev/next button in addition to this basic functionality. I would basically just like to get the current active item and then go to next/previous item with the next/prev buttons. How should this be implemented in practice? I tried this so that I'm evaluating the isVisible property and check which box is active and then go to adjacent box but I couldn't get that working and the solution itself doesn't seem very clean. Should I have some kind of indexing for the items and build an array to loop the items in it? I have following fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/cm70947/zq59tw7a/

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppController">
<div class="Button" ng-click="animateBox('first box')">button</div>
<div class="Animated_Box" id="first" ng-show="isVisible == 'first     box'">Animated Box 1</div>
<div class="Button" ng-click="animateBox('second box')">button</div>
<div class="Animated_Box" id="second" ng-show="isVisible =='second box'">Animated Box 2</div>
<div class="Button" ng-click="animateBox('third box')">button</div>
<div class="Animated_Box" id="third" ng-show="isVisible =='third box'">Animated Box3</div>

<div id="navigation">
<div class="naviButton" id="goUp" ng-click="prevItem()">PREV</div>
<div class="naviButton" id="goDown" ng-click="nextItem()">NEXT</div>
</div>
</body>
```

JS:
    myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('myAppController', function($scope) {

```
$scope.isVisible = 'first box';

$scope.animateBox = function (box) {
    if(box == $scope.isVisible){
        $scope.isVisible = null;
    }else{
        $scope.isVisible = box;
    }

}

$scope.prevItem = function () {

 //?
 }; 

});
```